# Which one is better in terms of space/time complexity?

Tags: java, if-statement, time-complexity, big-o

in terms of space/time complexity, which is better?

```
if (!(N % 2 == 0) || N % 2 == 0 && (N >= 6 && N <= 20)) {
  System.out.println("Weird");
} 
if ( N % 2 == 0 && (N >= 2 && N <= 5 || N > 20)) {
  System.out.println("Not Weird");
}

// OR

if (!(N % 2 == 0)) {
  System.out.println("Weird");
} else {
  if (N >= 2 && N <= 5) {
    System.out.println("Not Weird");
  }  if (N >= 6 && N <= 20) {
        System.out.println("Weird");
  }  if (N > 20) {
        System.out.println("Not Weird");
  }
}
```

I'm trying to see whether the best way to create if statements in Java is to make simple but direct if statements such as the one below (but a bit messier) or the 'neat' one on the top. Every small detail would be appreciated.

Comment: No loops. They are both O(1). Hope that helps.

Comment: Use whichever version seems more readable to you (and/or to your co-workers)

Answer (score 0):

**These are identical.**

Big-O only comes into play if you have loops, these both run in constant time `O(1)`.

Typically, avoid nesting. Personally I much prefer the first option. But there is really no difference at all, especially because of short circuiting:

If `!(N % 2 == 0)` is `true` in your first example, the `||` will "short circuit", meaning that because it has found a truth it won't evaluate its right half. This is the same in your if statements in the second example. The same holds true for `&&` operators - they "short circuit" if they encounter a single `false` value, as they can never evaluate to true that way.

So, essentially, **pick either that you prefer / is more readable / more coherent logically**.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, the space/time complexity is the same for both cases. The important factor here is complexity of understanding the code. That comes down to individual judgement in specific cases.

I'm not sure which I prefer, because I don't understand the algorithm for weirdness, and my preference depends on how 'obvious' either formulation is to the informed reader - I assume that anyone touching this code knows what it means for N to be weird.

But in the second case I'd prefer fewer comparisons. If one clause handles N <= 5 the next alternative doesn't need to ensure N >= 6.

Thus (in pseudocode)

```
else if (N <= 1) {
   // no decision according to original code
} else if (N <= 5) {
   print not weird   
} else if (N <= 20) {
   print weird
} else {
   print not weird
}
```

Is it the case that N is either weird or not weird?  Then, firstly, `else` is called for to avoid repeating the calculation, and secondly, did you mean to omit consideration of zero and the negative integers?  (I ask this from the point of view that my proposed layout makes it clear we don't do anything for such cases, and I'm arguing for clarity of exposition - the intended reader may have to wonder about that apparent omission)

Also, while I'm nit-picking

```
(!(N % 2 == 0))
```

is made clearer by writing it as

```
(N % 2 != 0)
```